# How can I implement "</>" into a string of HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I need to write a Javascript or (preferably) Typescript function that takes a string of mostly HTML, does something to it, and returns valid HTML.
I had the idea that "</>" would be replaced with the correct closing tag, for example:

```html
<button>I'm a button</> I'm text!
```

would give:

```html
<button>I'm a button</button> I'm text!
```

And should work with attributes & nested "</>" occurrences too.
What I've tried:

```
const parse = (html: string): string => {
     // regex to match </> tags
    const regex = /<\/>/g;
    // stack to keep track of open tags
    const stack: string[] = [];
  
    // use a parser to parse the HTML and fill the stack with open tags
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
  
    // loop through all nodes and fill the stack with open tag names
    const nodes = doc.documentElement.childNodes;
    for (let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        const node = nodes[i];
       
        if (node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            // add the tag name to the stack
            stack.push((node as Element).tagName.toLowerCase());        
        }
    }
  
    // replace </> with corresponding closing tag
    const result = html.replace(regex, () => {
      // get the last open tag from the stack
      const lastOpenTag = stack.pop();
      
      // construct the closing tag
      return `</${lastOpenTag}>`;
    });
    // return the HTML code
    return result
}
```

However, when trying it, this happened:

input:

```html
<button>I'm a button!</>
I am text!
```

output:

```html
<button>I'm a button! I am text!</button>
```

Can you help me fix this function?

Comment: Where does that come from in the first place? This would be a lot easier to fix upstream, by simply... not.

Comment: You can't use a DOM parser for something that isn't valid input to begin with.

Comment: oh ok. time to write my own parser... eh. ill just use regexes probably. Or use another parser.

Comment: @jonrsharpe school project. I know, I had that same idea.

Comment: maybe this (https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-parser) might help...
Though, it is 5 years old.

Comment: Parsing (nearly-)HTML with regex is [famously problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3001761).

Comment: You could search forward for `</>` and from there search backward for the next HTML tag. A very basic implementation wouldn't consider all edge cases, but could work for your input.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Okay, maybe I won't use regex.

Comment: @jabaa Okay, ill look into that.

Answer (score 0):

I found a kinda solution.
It isn't exactly what I was looking for, but it is close enough.
I am aware this is very close to PHP, but for my purposes, it is fine.
Maybe ill switch the question mark for a hashtag.
It allows for this syntax:

```html
<?div>
tag content
</?>
```

To turn into:

```html
<div>
tag content
</div>
```

This is the code:

```
const findUnknownTags = (html:string):string => {
      // I am pretty sure this covers all cases. Correct me if I am wrong.
      const pattern = /<\?(\w+)>((?:(?!<\?|\?>).)*)<\/\?>/g;
      const matches = html.matchAll(pattern);
    
      for (const match of matches) {
        const rawTagName = match[1]
        const tagName = `<${match[1]}>`;
        const tagContent = match[2];
        const closingTag = `</${rawTagName}>`;
    
        html = html.replace(match[0], `${tagName}${tagContent}${closingTag}`);
      }
    
      return html;
    }
}
```

Comment: What about tags inside tags `<div><span></span></div>` ?

Comment: Oh, then that won't really work then. Maybe I'll make it recursive.